# Learn Blender from scratch

Tags: modeling

How much time would it take to learn from scratch (I know nothing about 3D modeling or Blender in particular) to create 3D models of buildings only? Where can I find good resources to start from?

Comment: start here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Comment: Amount of time may depend on resources you choose. If those are books / text lessons then it may be longer. If you combine them with video lessons from cgcookie or youtube it may take less time. Make sure to focus on education and not immediately trying to model any complex scenes while learning (you should model for practice, you shouldn't distract with unnecessary complexity).